# List of Stackoverflow questions should be migrated here.

Tags: discussion

Let's make a list of subjective questions of Stackoverflow that should be migrated here.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good idea, anyhow, it should be a community wiki.

Comment: @Trufa I knew it should be. But I found no option for making it a community wiki.

Comment: there's no need to make anything on this site CW.  There are no points awarded.

Comment: @Walter: Community wiki (isn't supposed to) have anything to do with reputation. It make the *content* editable to a larger portion of the community (i.e. more collaboration on the answers). Wiki-fied.

Comment: no, you couldn't but no worries. and @Walter my point is very well expressed by @Robert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're discussing this on [MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71731/programmers-is-about-to-go-live-which-questions-should-we-migrate/71734#71734). It's important for our users to get in discussion there to avoid dumping their trash here.

Comment: Indeed... there appears to be a lot of junk lately. The presence isn't so worrying as much as the *rate*. They're drowning out regular questions. I hope it's just a transitional phase. Otherwise, the migration rate should be capped.